# Variable expansion in exec in BeanShell

Tags: python, exec

My beanshell script is like below in which I am calling exec to execute a python script

```
String param="parameter1";
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("/usr/bin/python /path/script.py param");
```

In the python script the first parameter is "param" and not "parameter1" . Question is how to pass the value of param to the python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this way?

```
String param="parameter1";
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("/usr/bin/python /path/script.py " + param);
```